# Find generated files in Android Studio Hedgehog

Tags: android, android-studio

After update of Android Studio to Android Studio Hedgehog (2023.1.1) I'm not able to find files that are generated by Navigation Component (the files "...FragmentDirections"). The files are not shown in search results anymore. While in the earlier versions these files were shown in search results and I was able to open them, and on update of Android Studio all settings were restored from the previous version. Is that possible to find and open these files in this version of Android Studio?